# How do I clear the screen after each math equation?

Tags: python

I am writing a small math game and it does what I want, it randomly outputs a math problem and when the answer is correct a point gets added to the counter. However, after asking the user for their name and printing the welcome message, I want the screen to be cleared. I first wrote a screen clear test to see if the clear screen function works, which it does.

This is the test:

```py
from os import system, name
from time import sleep
import sys

def clear():
    # for windows

    if name == 'nt':
        _ = system('cls')

def spreken():
    print("More to clear")
    sleep(3)
    clear()

def spreek():
    print("Another test to test clear")
    sleep(3)
    clear()
    a = input("Yes or No? ")
    if a == "Y":
        print("Go to next one")
        sleep(3)
        clear()
        spreken()
    if a == "N":
        sys.exit()

def test():

    print("Please, clear this text!")
    sleep(5)
    clear()
    spreek()

print("Let us test this, first a long line of tekst"
"you will have lots of fun! \n"
                                                        "Lets take on the computer! \n"
                                                        "Show the computer who's boss!")
sleep(3)
clear()

test()
print("Was it cleared?")
sleep(3)
clear()
print("Yes it was!")`
```

This works fine, however, when I implement it in my maths game code, nothing happens, the screen doesn't get cleared not even once. Here is the math game code(I'm sure it can be better but the focus now is on the clear screen):

```py
import random
import sys
from os import system, name
from time import sleep

score = 0

def clear():


    if name == 'nt':
        _ = system('cls')

def math():
    clear()
    y = random.randint(1, 10)
    x = random.randint(1, y)
    maths = ["*", "+", "-"]
    z = random.choice(maths)

    counter = 0
    clear()

    while True:
        global score
        clear()
        try:
            b = int(input(f"How much is {y} {z} {x}? "))
            counter += 1
        except ValueError:
            print("Number please")
            continue

        if z == "*" and b == y * x:
            clear()
            print("Correct")
            print(f"Very good {name}")
            print(f"Number of tries: {counter}")
            clear()
            score = score + 1
            break
        if z == "+" and b == y + x:
            clear()
            print("Correct!")
            print(f"Very good {name}")
            print(f"Number of tries {counter}")
            clear()
            score = score + 1
            break
        if z == "-" and b == y - x:
            clear()
            print("Correct")
            print(f"Very good {name}")
            print(f"Number of tries: {counter}")
            score = score + 1
            clear()
            break
        else:
            print(f"Try again {name}")
            continue
    while True:

        try:

                a = input("Another game? Y for Yes, N for no: ")

            except ValueError:
            print("Must be Y or N")

        if a == "Y":
            sleep(3)
            clear()
            math()
    if a == "N":
        print("Correct: ", score, "")
        sleep(5)
        sys.exit()

while True:

    name = input("What is your name?")

    if name.isdigit():
        print("No number")
        continue
    else:
        print(f"Welcome to the mathgame {name}!")
        break

sleep(3)
clear()
print("Screen got cleared")
sleep(3)
clear()

math()
```

I used clear everywhere possible but it doesn't clear the screen even once. Any feedback would be really appreciated. Sorry if this is not the right way to show my code but this is my first question ever.

Comment: Behold: [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? The clear function that you use is not cross-platform

Comment: I am on Windows and using PyCharm to write and test my code

Comment: This is an excellent time to learn debugging strategies. Try adding a print statement in your clear function at several points. I'd add a print statement before the `if` statement, and one in the `if` statement. If the first one works but the second one doesn't, then you know that the issue is in your logical comparison. If neither of them print, then it's an issue with how you're calling the function.

Comment: The PyCharm built-in terminal emulator might not implement the Windows `cls` command. Try running it in a Command Prompt window.

Comment: blackbrandt: I changed clear() to: def clear():

    print("Testing clearing")
    if name == 'nt':
        print("Clearing screen")
        _ = system('cls')

Comment: blackbrandt: now it printsTesting clearing
Testing clearing
Testing clearing
Testing clearing and then it goes to "How much is?" So, what does it mean, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: By the way, the 4 times Testing clearing is not my typing error, it actually prints it 4 times

Comment: If you mean the pycharm internal terminal (i.e. the terminal tab) then `os.system('cls')` will clear the screen. This wont clear the run tool window.

Comment: btw there is some indent problems in your code sample around the "Another game? loop" With python indenting is critical, you should ensure that its correct after posting to ensure others can read what your code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

In your `clear` function you are using variable `name`, which you are importing from `os` library. However, later in your code, when you ask the user for their name, you define another variable named `name`. So, your `name` variable value now is whatever the user put there as their name (let's say, `"Bob"`).

When called, `clear` function is checking for the OS that is used, by comparing `name` variable with `'nt'`, to ensure you're using Windows. Since `name` is now `"Bob"`, you're comparing `"Bob"` to `'nt'`, which is `False`, so clearing command inside of `if` statement does not execute.

To solve this you can:

1. Change the name of your `name` variable to something like `name_` and change it everywhere in your code (except for your `clear` function).
2. Instead of importing `name` directly from `os` library, simply write:

   ```
   import os
   ```

   and then use `name` variable from it as

   ```
   os.name
   ```

In future, try not to use same names for your variables and your imports, also try avoiding reserved names, otherwise, you'll get something like this:

```
# outputs "lol", instead of <built-in function sleep> for the same reason
from time import sleep
sleep = "lol"
print(sleep)
```

Comment: Thank you all very much. I understand it now, it works with both clear and with the os.system(cls)! Thanks again to everybody! Indeed I encounter many indent problems still, it's something I really need to get better at still. I can not believe I missed the name thing lol!